# after click back button in main activity it going to back to login ,HOW TO STOP TO GO LOGIN AGAIN

Tags: android

i am very new to android ,my login activity was working fine but my problem is after login in to my app sucessesfully go to main activity,after enter into my main activity when i press back button it will go to again login page please any one help me how to solve that

login.class

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(mypreference, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


    String checkemail=sharedpreferences.getString("Email", "");
    String checkuid =sharedpreferences.getString("Uid", "");

    if (checkemail.length()>0 && checkuid.length()>0){
        Intent main = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(main);
    }


    username       =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_email);

    password       =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.input_password);

    login          =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_login);

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkvalid();
        }
    });

    signup_link=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.link_signup);
    signup_link.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent signup= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SignUp.class);
            startActivity(signup);
        }
    });

}
private void checkvalid()
{
    uname   =username.getText().toString();
    upassword=password.getText().toString();
    new AttemptLogin().execute();
    if (username.length()==0 || password.length()==0)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter all fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else
    {
        uname   =username.getText().toString();
        upassword=password.getText().toString();
        new AttemptLogin().execute();
    }
}

class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{
    /** * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog * */

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args)
    {

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",uname));
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",upassword));


        System.out.println("?????????" + postParameters);
        String response = null;
        try
        {
            response = SimpleHttpClient.executeHttpPost(LOGIN_URL,postParameters).toString();
            System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@"+response);
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            String errorMsg = e.getMessage();
        }
        return response;
    } /** * Once the background process is done we need to Dismiss the progress dialog asap * **/
protected void onPostExecute(String response)
{
    pDialog.dismiss();


    try {
        JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(response);

        status = jsonobject.getString("Status");
        message = jsonobject.getString("Message");


        if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("OK")){
            JSONArray childArray = jsonobject.optJSONArray("Result");

            if (childArray != null && childArray.length() > 0) {

                for (int k = 0; k < childArray.length(); k++) {
                    JSONObject objj = childArray.optJSONObject(k);
                    uid        = objj.getString("id");
                    user_name  = objj.getString("user_name");
                    user_email = objj.getString("user_email");
                    user_status = objj.getString("status");
                    user_mobile = objj.getString("mobile_number");

                    System.out.println("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"+user_name+user_email+user_mobile);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                    editor.putString("Email",  user_email);
                    editor.putString("Uid",    uid);
                    editor.putString("Uname",  user_name);
                    editor.putString("Status", user_status);
                    editor.putString("Mobile", user_mobile);
                    editor.commit();
                    Intent login= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(login);
                }
            }


            else{
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Registration Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

    } catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

}

Comment: Add finish() after startActivity();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever you don't want to load the previous activity on back press you should call `finish()` method after launching the new activity.

You need to `finish()` the login activity when login is successful.

Add

```
finish();
```

at the end of method  `startActivity();`

You might have to add any condition as per your requirement.